# Golang BigQuery - Handling Rows Which Contain Repeated Fields and Slicing them

Tags: go, google-bigquery

Golang newb here - trying to read data from BigQuery and do some additional processing.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

func main() {
    
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "my-project-id")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    q := client.Query(`SELECT my_field 
                    FROM my_dataset.my_table 
                    LIMIT 10`)

    it, err := q.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    for {
        var values []bigquery.Value
        err := it.Next(&values)
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
        }
        fmt.Println(values)
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[121210262 121214145]]
[[511217886 512511526 511244877]]
[[154171820 261877552 104715017 215875151]]
[[108842615 27082151]]
[[512524261 87188122 418462821]]
[[447104185 446617012]]
[[111204670 476128746 528222282 221441847 476065272 522410566 521860266 522128861 521850881 522448121]]
[[246571585 442251255]]
[[217524022 518027802 142047652 252212822]]
```

My Question:

How can I convert my repeated field to a list or a slice in Golang? If I change the line where I print out the line `fmt.Println(values)` to `fmt.Println(values[0][0])`, I get the following error

```
 values[0][0] (type "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery".Value does not support indexing)
```

For reference, each row in my dataset is a repeated field of integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two paths here:

1. You know the schema of the result/table, and want to load the rows into a purpose-built compatible datastructure.
2. You're dealing with arbitrary results/tables, and need to deal with schemas and result rows in a more dynamic fashion.

The simpler case is the first, where you know the schema and have a custom type you can leverage.  Here's a completely manufactured query that generates the array of integers you asked about, and uses a custom `resultRow` struct for loading result rows:

```
q := client.Query(
        // Query is nonsense; we use generate_array to both generate multiple rows
        // and int64 arrays of different lengths.
        `
        SELECT
            SESSION_USER() as User,
            GENERATE_ARRAY(0,in_val * 2) as Arr,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as T,
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                in_val
            FROM
                UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,4)) as in_val
        )
    `)

    it, err := q.Read(ctx)

    type resultRow struct {
        User string
        Arr  []int64
        T    time.Time
    }

    for {
        var row resultRow
        err := it.Next(&row)
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("User: %s, Arr has %d elements: %v, t: %s\n", row.User, len(row.Arr), row.Arr, row.T.Format(time.RFC3339Nano))
    }
    return nil
}
```

The more complex case is the arbitrary one, and the library exposes the `ValueLoader` interface to help with this pattern.  You can also forego that and do something clever with reflection and type switches.  It is worth noting if you go down this path that the `RowIterator` retains a schema reference. However, schema is not populated on the iterator until the first call to Next().

Answer (score 1):

Purely BigQuery answer (vs @shollyman's `go` specific answer)

You can just UNNEST that field in your query - so you will not need to extra handle it in the go script

```
q := client.Query(`SELECT field 
                FROM my_dataset.my_table, 
                UNNEST(my_field) field`)
```